# "select_for_update" called from an atomic block still TransactionManagementError

Tags: django, postgresql, celery

I am working with django on a large project.

I call a celery `task` from inside the `save` of a model that calls a method which calls another method in a loop. That is:

```
celery task --> function A()
A() --> for i in range(1,100): call function B()
```

Now `B()` is wrapped with an `atomic()` decorator and has a `select_for_update` call inside it.

I still get `TransactionManagementError('select_for_update cannot be used outside of a transaction.',)`

I do not know why this is. I have tested with delaying the task by a few seconds so that the `save` is committed by the time the task is called. Did not help.

My question is: **Why am I getting a `TransactionManagementError` when I am already inside an atomic block?**

Answer (score 2):

@ketanbhatt This might help

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update

> Evaluating a queryset with select_for_update() in autocommit mode on backends which support SELECT ... FOR UPDATE is a TransactionManagementError error because the rows are not locked in that case. If allowed, this would facilitate data corruption and could easily be caused by calling code that expects to be run in a transaction outside of one.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#managing-autocommit

> Django will refuse to turn autocommit off when an atomic() block is active, because that would break atomicity.